# Ornstein-Uhlenbeck process

Tags: stochastic-processes, multivariate-distribution, stochastic-calculus

Given a multivariate Ornstein-Uhlenbeck process that is a stochastic process, is it correct that each component of this process is a univariate Ornstein-Uhlenbeck process?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that the vector valued process $X_t\in\mathbb{R}^n$ can be described via
$$
d X_t = -\Psi X_t \,dt + \sigma\, dW_t 
$$
where $\Psi=(\psi_1,\ldots,\psi_n)$ and $\sigma=(\sigma_1\,\ldots,\sigma_n)$ are both *constant* and *diagonal* matrices, then yes.

The $i$th component is 
$$ dx_{i,t} = -\psi_i x_{i,t}\, dt + \sigma_i\, dW_{i,t} $$
which is a univariate OU process.

Note that if $\sigma$ is not diagonal, then the component processes are still OU, but are no longer independent (as noted by the comment below).

Comment: I think only $\Psi$ needs to be diagonal.  If $\sigma$ is not diagonal, the components would still marginally be univariate OU processes, although the components would not be independent.

Comment: @JarleTufto very true, I've added that to the answer.

Comment: Thanks both for your answers!